# EF using LINQ trying Contains In passing in a Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

Is there a better way to write this CONTAINS from an ARRAY?

I am passing a string/array into my LINQ statement. In SQL the code that is working is

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.option1 
 WHERE option1Code IN ('9841','V237','SV02','2057')
```

In EF using LINQ I am trying

```
            using (var ctx = new ProductEntities())
        {
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
            string csvSKU = '984,237,102,207';
            string[] mArray = csvSKU.Split(',');
            var results = (from o in ctx.option1
                           join p in ctx.Products on o.option1Code equals p.productSKU
                           where mArray.Contains(o.option1Code)                                    
                           orderby o.option1Sort
                           select o).Distinct().ToList();

            return results;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks perfectly fine and should result in similar SQL as you posted (at least for the `Contains` part).

Also not really sure what your join is for right now - are there any option codes that have no entry in the `Products` table / `productSKU`?

Comment: Thanks- the code is working so I will leave it. YOU are correct, I do NOT need the PRODUCTS table at all :)